# PHP/WordPress Parse Error, Unexpected '?'

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing

I am having trouble fixing the following error in my WordPress theme's file.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wp-content\plugins\stoni-core\includes\theme-helper\theme-helper.php on line 23

The site has two staging(DEV/UAT) sites and a live(PROD) site, and the UAT and PROD sites share the exact same files as the DEV, yet the DEV is spitting out the error.

I have tried every solution that I have seen to fix the error(I am not great at PHP but I know enough to get by). I have copied the working files from PROD to DEV and I got the same error. I have redownloaded the theme files(with the thought that they may be corrupted) and that also spits out the same error.

If anybody has any recommendations, that would be greatly appreciated as I have been researching and manipulating for days to no avail.

```
    <?php
class WglThemeHelper{

    protected static $instance = null;

    /**
     * @var \WP_Post
     */
    private $post_id;

    public static function instance() {
        if ( is_null( self::$instance ) ) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    } 

    private function __construct () {
        $this->post_id = get_the_ID();
    }

    public function render_post_share ($show_share) {
        $img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($this->post_id), 'single-post-thumbnail')[0] ?? '';

        if ($show_share == "1" || $show_share == "yes") :
        ?>
            <!-- post share block -->
            <div class="share_social-wpapper">                  
                <a class="share_link share_twitter" target="_blank" href="<?php echo esc_url('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='. get_the_title() .'&amp;url='. get_permalink()); ?>"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a>
                <a class="share_link share_facebook" target="_blank" href="<?php echo  esc_url('https://www.facebook.com/share.php?u='. get_permalink()); ?>"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a>
                <?php
                    if (strlen($img_url) > 0) {
                        echo '<a class="share_link share_pinterest" target="_blank" href="'. esc_url('https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='. get_permalink() .'&media='. $img_url) .'"><span class="fa fa-pinterest-p"></span></a>';
                    }
                ?>
                <a class="share_link share_linkedin" href="<?php echo esc_url('http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url='.substr(urlencode( get_permalink() ),0,1024));?>&title=<?php echo esc_attr(substr(urlencode(html_entity_decode(get_the_title())),0,200));?>" target="_blank" ><span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span></a>
            </div>
            <!-- //post share block -->
        <?php
        endif;
    }

    public function render_post_list_share(){
        ?>
        <div class="share_post-container">
            <a href="#"></a>
            <div class="share_social-wpapper">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a class="share_post share_twitter" target="_blank" href="<?php echo esc_url('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='. get_the_title() .'&amp;url='. get_permalink()); ?>"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a>                
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="share_post share_facebook" target="_blank" href="<?php echo  esc_url('https://www.facebook.com/share.php?u='. get_permalink()); ?>"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a>            
                    </li> 
                    <?php
                    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()), 'single-post-thumbnail')[0] ?? '';
                    if (strlen($img_url) > 0) {
                        echo '<li>';
                        echo '<a class="share_post share_pinterest" target="_blank" href="'. esc_url('https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='. get_permalink() .'&media='. $img_url) .'"><span class="fa fa-pinterest"></span></a>';
                        echo '</li>';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <li>
                        <a class="share_post share_linkedin" target="_blank" href="<?php echo esc_url('http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url='.substr(urlencode( get_permalink() ),0,1024));?>&title=<?php echo esc_attr(substr(urlencode(html_entity_decode(get_the_title())),0,200));?>"><span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span></a>                                    
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>      
        <?php
    }

    public static function render_social_shares(){
        $description = esc_html__('Socials', 'stoni-core');

        $facebook    = Stoni_Theme_Helper::options_compare('soc_icon_facebook', 'mb_customize_soc_shares', 'on');
        $twitter     =  Stoni_Theme_Helper::options_compare('soc_icon_twitter', 'mb_customize_soc_shares', 'on');
        $linkedin    = Stoni_Theme_Helper::options_compare('soc_icon_linkedin', 'mb_customize_soc_shares', 'on');
        $pinterest   = Stoni_Theme_Helper::options_compare('soc_icon_pinterest', 'mb_customize_soc_shares', 'on');
        $tumblr      = Stoni_Theme_Helper::options_compare('soc_icon_tumblr', 'mb_customize_soc_shares', 'on');

        $fixed   = Stoni_Theme_Helper::options_compare('soc_icon_position', 'mb_customize_soc_shares', 'on');
        $offset = Stoni_Theme_Helper::get_option('soc_icon_offset');
        if (class_exists( 'RWMB_Loader' ) && get_queried_object_id() !== 0) {
            $mb_social_shares = rwmb_meta('mb_customize_soc_shares');
        
            if ($mb_social_shares == 'on') {
                $offset = array();
                $offset['margin-bottom'] = rwmb_meta('mb_soc_icon_offset');
            }
        }   

        $share = Stoni_Theme_Helper::options_compare('soc_icon_style', 'mb_customize_soc_shares', 'on');
        $share_class = !empty($share) ? " ".$share.'_style' : ' standard_style';
        $share_class .= !empty($fixed) ? " fixed" : '';

        $units = !empty($fixed) ? "%" : 'px';
        $style = '';
        $style .=  isset($offset['margin-bottom']) && $offset['margin-bottom'] !== '' ? ' top:'.(int)$offset['margin-bottom'].$units.';' : '';                

        ?>
        <section class="wgl-social-share_pages<?php echo esc_attr($share_class);?>"<?php
            echo !empty($style) ? ' style="'.$style.'"' : ''
        ?>>
            <div class="share_social-wpapper">
                <?php
                    if($share == 'hovered'):
                ?>
                    <div class="share_social-desc">
                        <div class="share_social-title">
                        <?php
                            echo apply_filters('stoni_desc_socials', $description);
                        ?>                                
                        </div>
                        <div class="share_social-icon-plus"></div>
                    </div>
                <?php
                    endif;
                ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php
                    if(!empty($twitter)):
                    ?>
                        <li>
                            <a class="share_page share_twitter" target="_blank" href="<?php echo esc_url('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='. get_the_title() .'&amp;url='. get_permalink()); ?>"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a>                
                        </li>
                    <?php
                    endif;
                    ?>

                    <?php
                    if(!empty($facebook)):
                    ?>
                    <li>
                        <a class="share_page share_facebook" target="_blank" href="<?php echo  esc_url('https://www.facebook.com/share.php?u='. get_permalink()); ?>"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a>            
                    </li>

                    <?php
                    endif;
                    ?>  

                    <?php
                    if(!empty($share_pinterest)):
                    ?>     
                    <?php
                    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()), 'single-post-thumbnail')[0] ?? '';
                    if (strlen($img_url) > 0) {
                        echo '<li>';
                        echo '<a class="share_page share_pinterest" target="_blank" href="'. esc_url('https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='. get_permalink() .'&media='. $img_url) .'"><span class="fa fa-pinterest"></span></a>';
                        echo '</li>';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <?php
                    endif;
                    ?>  


                    <?php
                    if(!empty($linkedin)):
                    ?>
                    <li>
                        <a class="share_page share_linkedin" target="_blank" href="<?php echo esc_url('http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url='.substr(urlencode( get_permalink() ),0,1024));?>&title=<?php echo esc_attr(substr(urlencode(html_entity_decode(get_the_title())),0,200));?>"><span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span></a>                                    
                    </li>
                    <?php
                    endif;
                    ?>                         

                    <?php
                    if(!empty($tumblr)):
                    ?>
                    <li>
                        <a class="share_page share_tumblr" target="_blank" href="<?php echo esc_url( 'http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url=' . urlencode(get_permalink()). '&amp;name=' . urlencode(get_the_title()) .'&amp;description='.urlencode(get_the_excerpt()) );?>"><span class="fa fa-tumblr"></span></a>                                    
                    </li>
                    <?php
                    endif;

                    $custom_share = Stoni_Theme_Helper::get_option('add_custom_share');
                    if(isset($custom_share) && !empty($custom_share)){
                        for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
                            ${'custom_share_'.$i} = Stoni_Theme_Helper::get_option('select_custom_share_text-'.$i);
                            ${'custom_share_icons'.$i} = Stoni_Theme_Helper::get_option('select_custom_share_icons-'.$i);
                            
                            if (!empty(${'custom_share_'.$i})) {
                                ?>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="share_page" href="<?php echo esc_url( ${'custom_share_'.$i} );?>"><span class="<?php echo esc_attr(${'custom_share_icons'.$i});?>"></span></a>                                    
                                </li>
                                <?php                                   
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ?> 
                </ul>
            </div>                
        </section>
        <?php
    }
    
}

function wgl_theme_helper() {
    return WglThemeHelper::instance();
}
?>
```

Comment: Without code, it's hard to tell, but make sure that all environments are running the same version of PHP

Comment: The null coalescing operator (`??`) was introduced in PHP 7.0. Are you really sure DEV is also running PHP 7+?

Comment: @ZoliSzabó It appears I was not on 7.4.1 , as were the other sites. I will update this accordingly, as I am hoping this is the final straw. Thanks for the help!